# Create an account to manipulate database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to figure out how to make a user account for a database that I make in php.

I can easly create in phpMyAdmin but I would like to know if is possible to make directly in php, and setup all the permission for the database I create.

```
        if($stmt = $this->runQuery("CREATE DATABASE ".$namedatabase)){
        $stmt->execute(array(':unamedatabase'=>$namedatabase));
        }else{
        }
```

I use this code for making a DATABASE and works perfect, now, I try to find somewhere if is possible to create an account to associate to that database but I dnd't find anything.

Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't look like `mysqli` code, it's PDO based on that notation. Also you can't bind database or column names like that, it's not a supported feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new user an grant all privilegues of the given database to that user. You could even do this in a single MySQL statement like this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* To 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

where hostname is often just localhost

Comment: yes, this is what I want, because my user can make his own database, but I would like to make a new user for manipulate only that database, generate by a random pass and username. so, I should use your code like: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $namedatabase.* To '$nameuser'@'server' IDENTIFIED BY 'randompassword' ? thank you very much

Comment: @Ribis Hopefully you will block names like `information_schema` or `mysql` and nobody uses the same name.

Comment: I tried "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbtest.* To 'aaaaaaa'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY '1234567'" and works, but the user has not privilege... is that normal? how I can set up some privilege? @JustOnUnderMillions, I will generate a randomstring+nameusername + random password

Comment: maybe you should also execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after you create the new user

Comment: @Philipp thank you for the answer, is possible to decide a PRIVILEGES with some array? how I can menage the different PRIVILEGES? I try to find on internet but I didn't find anything... thank you

Comment: Instead of `ALL`, you could grant a list of specific privileges to the given user, i.e. only select, update and delete. Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html